# Solution to a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Suppose $f'(x)=\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}$ for all $x \in (0,1]$, what are the solutions?

In my problem, $f'(x)$ is also continuous negative.

Comment: it works for $f(x)=c$ where $c < 0$

Comment: Right, although I would also like $f'(x)<0$, which excludes constant function. More generally, it works for all linear functions $a-bx$ with $b>0$. Also, if $f$ is a polynomial, then it must be linear. Are there any other functions than linear (and constant)?

Comment: Trying $f(x)=ax^b$ gives as condition $b=2^b-1$ which has solutions $b=0$ and $b=1$, so all functions $f(x)=ax+c$.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas how to prove that there are no continuously differentiable non-linear functions that satisfy the equation?

Comment: I'm wondering whether Weierstrass Theorem could be used here? Intuitively, since $f(x)$ is continuous, it can be closely approximated by polynomials. The only polynomials that (exactly) satisfy the equation are of degree 1, i.e. linear. This seems to give a strong hint that $f(x)$ itself must be linear. But I'm not famililar with these techniques, so I would appreciate some pointers.